# Structures whose set of homomorphisms is itself said structure?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, logic, category-theory

Given two vector spaces $V,W$ over $K$, the set of linear maps $f:V\longrightarrow W$ is itself a vector space.

Are there any other structures for which any given two $A,B$, the set $Hom(A,B)$ is itself a structure of the same kind?

Comment: Possibly relevant terms include "abelian category" and "enriched category."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A category like this is said to possess an [internal hom](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/internal+hom) or to be a [closed category](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/closed+category). There are roughly two classes of examples of categories with this property, "linear" examples which generalize vector spaces and "nonlinear" examples which generalize sets.

"Linear" examples ([closed monoidal categories](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/closed+monoidal+category) where the monoidal structure is some kind of "tensor product") include abelian groups, vector spaces, $R$-modules for $R$ a commutative ring, linear representations of groups, Banach spaces, chain complexes, etc.

"Nonlinear" examples ([cartesian closed categories](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/cartesian+closed+category)) include sets, group actions, [sheaves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sheaf_(mathematics)) of sets, and more generally any [topos](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/topos#ElementaryTopos).

Comment: Excellent thank you very much!

Comment: Under linear examples, you also have sheaves of abelian groups, or sheaves of modules on a ringed space.  Under nonlinear examples, you have directed graphs (yes, that's technically a special case of a category of presheaves, but a particularly interesting special case...).